# Ripple cant find config.xml after upgrading cordova project to visual studio 2015

Tags: android, angularjs, visual-studio, cordova, ionic-framework

I followed the instructions at the end of this video and the project actually builds and seems to work in ripple. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n44ynSECDCY

However, in the console there is a 404 on finding the config.xml which is located on the project root in 2015 cordova projects. If I make a copy of the config.xml and place it in the www directory I no longer get the error in ripple.

Obviously I shouldn't have to have the config.xml in two different places so some sort of path needs to be fixed. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: Looks like this happens on a new 2015 project as well

Answer (score 0):

I just make a copy of the config.xml too.

as suggested here you can add a Post Build task to copy the config.xml over:

```
<Copy SourceFiles="config.xml" DestinationFolder="www" ContinueOnError="false" />
```

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c289c125-a7cf-409a-a126-85743a811058/vs-2015-cordova-app-configxml?forum=ToolsForApacheCordova